# How do I put a computer into an Active Directory machine group?

Tags: active-directory

How do I put a computer into an Active Directory machine group?

I have server INTRANET1 and it needs to be in the intranet.gpo.mg machine group.

** EDIT **

So, I used the dsa.msc tool to search for my computer name. I right-clicked on the computer, and chose Properties. There is a tab called "Member of." I went to the "Member of" tab and searched for the intranet.gpo.mg group and added it to the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Active Directory Users and Computers Snap-In you can add Users or Computers to groups.

Rob